# Firebase signin with email link on iOS without 'open link in app'?

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication

I use passwordless login in my mobile app. That is done with Firebase Authentication.

When I open a magic link on iOS it first takes me to `preview.page.link` which displays the `Open link in app?` page. Whereas on Android it goes straight to the app.

Is there anyway to avoid that step on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you described is specific to iOS devices and is intended for security purposes. iOS handles universal links differently than Android does with deep links.

When a magic link is opened on an iOS device, it is first intercepted by the operating system, which checks if the app associated with the link is installed. If the app is installed, iOS will open the app directly. However, if the app is not installed, iOS will redirect the user to a preview page (in this case, `preview.page.link`) to provide a preview of the content and give the user the option to open the link in the app.

This behavior is designed to prevent malicious apps from intercepting and stealing sensitive information. It provides an extra layer of security by allowing users to preview the content before deciding to open it in the app. Unfortunately, this behavior cannot be bypassed or changed programmatically by the app developer.

"Therefore, it is not possible to avoid the intermediate step on iOS and have the same behavior as on Android. Users on iOS will always see the "Open link in app?" page when opening a magic link, regardless of whether the app is already installed or not."

Comment: > When a magic link is opened on an iOS device
> it is first intercepted by the operating system, which checks if the app associated > with the link is installed

The app is already installed on the device. How do I make sure that the that check succeeds?

Comment: 1-) Configure Universal Links: Universal Links allow iOS to associate specific URLs with your app. Make sure you have correctly configured Universal Links for your app. This involves creating an apple-app-site-association file and hosting it on your server. 

2-) Associate the app with the link: When generating the magic link, ensure that it contains the necessary metadata to associate it with your app. This metadata should match the configuration in your apple-app-site-association file. This association typically involves specifying the Team ID, Bundle ID, and the URL path or domain.